# Scala variable with empty string returning true when checking if all are digits

Tags: scala

When I have a string variable `x` that for some reason is `""`:

`val x = ""`

and I do:
`x.forall(_.isDigit)` it returns `true`

I'm a little perplexed why it's true, shouldn't it be false?
I found this out the hard way when my if condition wasn't working.
Then I went to see the Scala source code:

```
private def prefixLengthImpl(p: A => Boolean, expectTrue: Boolean): Int = {
    var i = 0
    while (i < length && p(apply(i)) == expectTrue) i += 1
    i
  }

  override /*IterableLike*/
  def forall(p: A => Boolean): Boolean = prefixLengthImpl(p, expectTrue = true) == length
```

So apparently it's holding the "Vacuous Truth" principle, and since the counter variable `i` is returned as `0` and the length of my string is also `0`, it ends up being `0==0` hence `true`. I find that it shouldn't be necessary to do a `x.isEmpty` before doing the `forall`.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 6):

I don't see the problem.  The scala `forall` method follows the [basic first-order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification#The_empty_set), which minimizes surprise.  For your specific example you should probably be using the regex `"".matches("\\d+")` anyway.

Comment: Agreed. I usually explain this as: 1) Forall is true as long as no element fails the predicate; 2) Exists is true as long as at least one element satisfies the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `forall` with `exists`:

```
str.exists(_.isDigit) && str.forall(_.isDigit)
// returns true for "123", false for "", false for "1nodigits"
```

Comment: If I was taking this approach, I'd probably go for the `exists` plus a non-empty test.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

It's just a fact that every character in "" is a digit.